# Email attachment trouble in Python 3.3

Tags: python, email, attachment

I'm trying to send a PDF through email attachment in Python 3.3. I searched for how to do it and found this code in another question on this site:

```
import smtplib, os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import encoders

def send_mail( send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=[], server="localhost", port=587, username='', password='', isTls=True):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

    for f in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="{0}"'.format(os.path.basename(f)))
        msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
    if isTls: smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(username,password)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
```

I call the function with my inputs and get an error that reads:

```
File "C:\Python33\mailAttach.py", line 46, in send_mail
    msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )
File "C:\Python33\lib\email\mime\text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It can not be said for sure but probably the problem is in those inputs you mention and do not report.
For example, this code gives no problem:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) on Windows (64 bits).
This is the IEP interpreter.
Type "help" for help, type "?" for a list of *magic* commands.
>>> from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart as MM
>>> from email.mime.text import MIMEText as MT
>>> msg = MM()
>>> msg.attach(MT('hello'))
```

But if you send the `text` parameter as a list, then you get exactly the traceback you report:

```
>>> msg.attach(MT(['hello']))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python33\lib\email\mime\text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: The problem was in my inputs. I was missing a comma between arguments... Thanks for your help.